# How to loop through a json object and insert into html page as select form field options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

Working in a Laravel project, I'm trying to use javascript Ajax to update a form select fields options, each time another select fields value is changed.

I currently have all the data being returned to my view and can see it in the console log. I have ran into this problem before, I basically can't wrap my head around how to loop through a json object with javascript. I can get only currently get one of the two data results being returned to display as a select option.

The code below is from my controller that gets the data when the ajax request is made, this is how I'm currently passing back the data.

```php
$templates = DB::table('templates')->where("page_name", "=", $page)->get();

      return response()->json([
        'status' => true,
        'templates' => $templates
      ]);
```

This is how that data is then being displayed in the console.

```
{status: true, templates: Array(2)}
status: true
templates: Array(2)
0:
created_at: "2019-06-17 22:29:44"
css: "somecss"
html: "somehtml"
id: 1
page_name: "page-1"
template_name: "template-1"
updated_at: "2019-06-17 22:29:44"
__proto__: Object
1:
created_at: "2019-06-18 01:30:49"
css: "somecss"
html: "somehtml"
id: 3
page_name: "page-1"
template_name: "template-2"
updated_at: "2019-06-18 01:30:49"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

And finally this is how I am currently trying to loop through and display that data using javascript/jquery.

```
       success: function(data) {
         if(data.status == true) {
             $.each(data.templates, function(i, template) {
                 $('#template-select').html('<option value="' + template.template_name + '">' + template.template_name + '</option>');
             });
         }
        }
```

Currently only "template-2" is displaying as a select option, when there should be both a "template-1" and "template-2" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, change code to this:

```
success: function(data) {
         if(data.status == true) {
             $.each(data.templates, function(i, template) {
                 $('#template-select').append($('<option value="' + template.template_name + '">' + template.template_name + '</option>'));
             });
         }
        }
```